# The curve of shortest length bounding given area

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations

Is formula #7 in this [MIT OCW course](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-086-mathematical-methods-for-engineers-ii-spring-2006/readings/am72.pdf) incorrect? I think it should be
$$f(x)=(\sqrt{1-(mx-c)^2}+d)/m$$

Also, presumably [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/346874/) to a very similar problem is also wrong. 
Because this is not the correct solution to the differential equation

$$\lambda-\frac{1}{\big(1+(y')^2\big)^{3/2}}=0$$

Comment: I edited the question. Please pay more attention to the title and formatting in the future. The title should give an idea of what the question is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked MSE answer, which purports that the shortest curve is a parabola, is incorrect.

The linked OCW material is correct. Indeed, 
$$\frac{d}{dx} \left( -\frac{1}{m} \sqrt{1-(mx-c)^2} \right) =  \frac{mx-c}{\sqrt{1-(mx-c)^2}} $$
You dropped the minus sign somewhere.